# How to change probability in selectoutput block based on Agent parameter

Tags: anylogic

I have agents parameter values from 1-5 with different probabilities.
Agent Group 1 - 0.5
Agent Group 2- 0.3
...
...
Agent Group 5 0.1

When agent is passing through selectOutput block I want assign these probabilities.
Is it possible to do in Anylogic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use this syntax:

```
agent.parameter == 1 ? 0.5 : agent.parameter == 2 ? 0.3 : agent.parameter == 3 ? x : agent.parameter == 4 ? y : z
```

Replace x, y and z with the correct porbabilities.